# Why is the Jackson Object Mapper unable to deserialize this nested JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am in the process of updating some code to hit a new API which returns the same type of data but in a different JSON format. This is a sample of the return from a request:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "start_time": "2017-09-20T00:00:00.000-04:00",
            "end_time": "2017-09-21T00:00:00.000-04:00",
            "value": 8612.637512577203
        },
        {
            "start_time": "2017-09-21T00:00:00.000-04:00",
            "end_time": "2017-09-22T00:00:00.000-04:00",
            "value": 8597.89155775999
        },
        {
            "start_time": "2017-09-22T00:00:00.000-04:00",
            "end_time": "2017-09-23T00:00:00.000-04:00",
            "value": 24584.603303989123
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "space_id": "e1c38410-f912-4ae3-9db9-10a1ad1e3bf5",
        "channel_id": 1,
        "aggregation_type": "period_beginning",
        "pids_count": 1,
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
    }
}
```

I want to ignore the code and message properties, and put the array of data into a list within a map, with the key being the "space_id" property `(Map<String, List<Reading>>)` for compatibility with the old implementation. Here is the POJO that I have created to contain the deserialized object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"code", "message", "meta"})
public class GetReadingsResult {

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, List<Reading>> readings;

    @JsonIgnore
    public GetReadingsResult(Map<String, List<Reading>> readings) {
        this.readings = readings;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public GetReadingsResult(@JsonProperty("data")Reading[] data, @JsonProperty("space_id")String spaceId) {
        this.readings.put(spaceId, Arrays.asList(data));
    }

    //...other getters and setters...
}
```

In my test I am calling readValue on a test JSON file and getting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class model.GetReadingsResult] value failed: null
```

What is the proper way to set up/annotate my POJO to deal with this nested file?

Comment: The root JSON object doesn't have a `space_id`. If you want that value, you need to parse the `meta` object.

Comment: so how do I parse an object that isn't the root object?

Comment: You're already doing it with `Reading`, aren't you? Remove ignore of `meta` are get it parsed into an object, then extract the value from that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to implement.

Please pay attention to object point of view of all thing:

These are the pojos:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "start_time",
    "end_time",
    "value"
})
public class Datum {

    @JsonProperty("start_time")
    public String startTime;
    @JsonProperty("end_time")
    public String endTime;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Double value;

}


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "space_id",
    "channel_id",
    "aggregation_type",
    "pids_count",
    "timezone"
})
public class Meta {

    @JsonProperty("space_id")
    public String spaceId;
    @JsonProperty("channel_id")
    public Integer channelId;
    @JsonProperty("aggregation_type")
    public String aggregationType;
    @JsonProperty("pids_count")
    public Integer pidsCount;
    @JsonProperty("timezone")
    public String timezone;

}
```

This is the wrapper root Object:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "code",
    "message",
    "data",
    "meta"
})
public class ExampleStack {

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public Integer code;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<Datum> data = null;
    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public Meta meta;

}
```

And this is the working example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;//<--IMPORTANT!

public class TestJacksonObject {


     public static void main(String[] args) {


         ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper(); 
         ExampleStack stack = null;
            try {
                stack = mapper .readValue( new FileInputStream(new File("C://test.json")) , ExampleStack.class);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    System.out.println(stack.message);//<--Do whatever you want...
.....
```

If it's too hard to produce all these classes, which is actually tedious I suggest you to autoproduce them online through this useful site:

[Json2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Hope it helps you out!